# onclick of multiple checbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

my code is as follows

```
<script>
function search()
{
 var bed = document.getElmentById("bed").value;
alert(bed);
}
</script>

    <input type="checkbox" id="bed" name="bed" value="1" onClick="search()"/>1 BHK <br/>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="bed" name="bed" value="2" onClick="search()"/>2 BHK  <br/>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="bed" name="bed" value="3" onClick="search()"/>3 BHK  <br/>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="bed" name="bed" value="4" onClick="search()"/>4 BHK  <br/>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="bed" name="bed" value="5" onClick="search()"/>5 BHK  <br/>
```

When i click on any of the checkbox i get only first value.

Comment: you should be using an array of check boxes

Comment: By convention, you can't have multiple id's. So change your id's. Or your mechanism. You can also remove the id and call `onClick="search(this)"` you will get, in your search function, the checkbox element that you clicked on. And you will be able to do:

function search(elt){
   var bed=elt.value;
   alert(bed);
}

Answer (score 0):

All the checkboxes have the same id. This means that `document.getElementById("bed")` will always return the first element with the id "bed". In your case this is `<input type="checkbox" id="bed" name="bed" value="1" onClick="search()"/>`. Try giving it other different id's or like said in the comment, put it in an array.

Answer (score 0):

At first, if you want one value from an input group, you should use input type radio (radio button), and you never write the same id for different DOM elements.

The code below is a solution with jquery:

```js
function search()
{
  var bed = $( "input[name=bed]:checked" ).val();
  alert(bed);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="bed" value="1" onClick="search()"/>1 BHK <br/>
<input type="radio" name="bed" value="2" onClick="search()"/>2 BHK <br/>
<input type="radio" name="bed" value="3" onClick="search()"/>3 BHK <br/>
<input type="radio" name="bed" value="4" onClick="search()"/>4 BHK <br/>
<input type="radio" name="bed" value="5" onClick="search()"/>5 BHK <br/>
```